# Showing a function can't be even

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would you show that there are no non-zero values of $k$ for which $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}+\sin(kx)$ is an even function? $f$ is an even function when $f(x)-f(-x)=0$, so I guess I need to show that $\sin(kx)=\sin(-kx)$ has no solutions for k. I'm not sure how to do that though. Can I just equate the arguments and say $kx \ne -kx$ for $k\ne 0$?

I'm actually more interested in finding a more general $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}+g(x)$ that has lots of turning points but is also symmetric about the y-axis. I thought a trig function would be a neat choice because you can just increase the period, but obviously not.

Comment: Hint: sin $(-\theta)=-$ sin $\theta$

Comment: Oh, of course. And so $g(x)=\cos(kx)$ works for my other question. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, you are only to show there exists $k \neq 0$ such that $\sin(kx) = \sin(-kx)$, but not for all $k \neq 0$, $\sin(kx) \neq \sin(-kx)$.

For the second question, definitely not. Two different arguments $x_1 \neq x_2$ is the domain can produce the same image $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$. Just think of $f(x) = 0$. Therefore it is, in general, not sufficient to think of $kx \neq -kx$, unless the function is injective.

Instead this question simply asks for some $k \neq 0$ and $x \neq 0$ such that $f(x) \neq f(-x)$ and as you have seen $\sin(kx) \neq \sin(-kx)$. It is easy since $\sin(x)$ is an odd function and just pick $k = 1$ and $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\sin$ is an odd function, we can continue where you left off:
$$\sin(kx) = \sin(-kx) = -\sin(kx)$$
If a function is equal to its negative for all $x$, it must be the constant zero function, so $k$ must be zero. Since $k$ is nonzero by assumption, we have a contradiction, and so there is no such $k$ for which $f(x)$ is even.

If you assume your general $f(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2} + g(x)$ is also even, then $g(x)$ must also be even, since the $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ term cancels in the equation $f(x) = f(-x)$.